# percentages when converting sterling to euro

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to convert Sterling to Euros. But I can't seem to get the percentages correct. I have tried it several ways without luck. The idea is to get 1% of the sterling price then multiply it by the conversion rate and add it to the sterling price to make the euro total, and then do the same with vat.
Hope someone can help, thanks!
Here is my code.

```js
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    var conversionRate = input[0];
    var sterling = input[1];
    var vat = input[2];
    var euro = input[3];

    init();

    function init() {
        calculateKeyUp();
    }

    function calculateKeyUp() {
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            input[i].addEventListener("keyup", function() {
                //var totalLessVat = (sterling.value) + (conversionRate.value * (sterling.value / 100));
                var sterling1Per = sterling.value / 100;
                var convert = sterling1Per * conversionRate.value;
                var totalLessVat = convert + sterling.value;
                //var total =  (totalLessVat) + (vat.value * (totalLessVat / 100));
                var euro1Per = totalLessVat / 100;
                var addVat = euro1Per * vat.value;
                var total = addVat + totalLessVat;
                euro.value = Math.floor(total);
            });
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="calculator-form">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Conversion Rate: </td>
            <td><input type="number" id="conversionRate"> %</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sterling Price: </td>
            <td><input type="number" id="sterling"> &pound;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vat: </td>
            <td><input type="number" id="vat"> %</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Euro Price is </td>
            <td><input type="number" id="euro" disabled> &euro;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: would you mind adding a snippet so we can run the program?

Answer (score 0):

The `.value` of an input is going to be a `String`, so you will need to parse the number out of each input you are working with. If it's an `int` you can use:

```
var sterling1Per = parseInt(sterling.value, 10) / 100;
```

If it's a float, you can use:

```
var sterling1Per = parseFloat(sterling.value) / 100;
```

Anywhere that you use an input `.value` that needs to be a number needs to be parsed accordingly

Comment: The multiplication/division is fine, it is the addition line that would have issues.

Comment: @epascarello Good point. I removed the part pointing out the specific line with multiplication and instead made it more general advice about using `parseInt` and `parseFloat`

Comment: Thanks guy's for putting me in the right direction! I just assumed it was getting the percentage that was the problem, but of course the addition was just appending the strings together. So I used +sterling.value + ... and that works perfect!